# Printing a winform C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I created an application which is larger in size than an A4 paper . I placed a print button on my windows form and following the MSDN tried both printDocument and printForm . But both of them don't scale my image and print only half the screen .

I researched and found that somewhere it was advised to place all controls in a picturebox and print that , but I am looking for a better alternative before I go ahead changing the complete design of my application . Some places advised to go for a completely different route for crystal reports .

The task doesn't seem easy than I actually thought and now I am stuck .

Edit1 :Here is the code that I added to my Form . I did try using bitmaps but that did not resolve the problem too .

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Form3 dlg = new Form3();
        //dlg.ShowDialog();

        //CaptureScreen();
       // printDocument2.Print();

        printForm1.Print();

    }

  /*  Bitmap memoryImage;

    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
    }

    private void printDocument2_PrintPage(System.Object sender,
           System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }

    private void groupBox4_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }*/
```

Is there a way if I can also possibly change the orientation to landscape ? I would like to try to see of that probably fits .

Edit2 : I found a way to print in the landscape mode and all the contents fit well . My application has a windows form and 3 tabs in it under a tab control . What I am trying to print is only the contents of the third tab which is the result window . Is there a way I can only print the contents of the tab control and not the entire form ?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Could you post relevant code snippets so we can understand the situation better?

Comment: You may want to try to have the form drawn into a bitmap (`Control.DrawToBitmap`) and then work with that. Obviously you can't process scrollable data lists etc that way..